# Query in compareTo function in Android

Tags: java, android

I have a query in compareTo.

I have 2 strings named todaydate and harvest_date.

They have values 2019-08-25 and 1901-11-11 respectively.

When i compare them,as per my understanding,the UNI code value of first character that differs should be returned which as per my understanding is 1.

However i get 18.

Please let me know where i am going wrong.

Thanks in advance.

```
                            Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
                            SimpleDateFormat mdformat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
                            String todaydate = "Current Date : " + mdformat.format(calendar.getTime());
                            year_harvest_date=1901;
                            month_harvest_date=11;
                            day_harvest_date=11;
                            String harvest_date=Integer.toString(year_harvest_date)+"-"+
                                    Integer.toString(month_harvest_date)+"-"
                                    +Integer.toString(day_harvest_date);
                            Log.e("todaydate",todaydate);
                            Log.e("harvest_date",harvest_date);
                            Log.e("today",Integer.toString(todaydate.compareTo(harvest_date)));
```

I expected 1 as output.However i get 18.
[image]

Answer (score 2):

compareTo returns >0 if the value it's called on is greater than the parameter passed in.  There is no promise to what the actual value is-  just whether its ==0, >0, or <0.  Anything else is implementation specific and can change at any time.  So either 1, 18, or 1038575 are all valid outputs when comparing those strings, and you can't assume that it will be a specific one of those.